# Calling navigation.navigate from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Today i spend 6 hours trying to figure this out, this is kind of my last resort.

I want to switch screens with react navigate. It works when all the screens are in the same file. but when i seperate them into multiple files (1 file for every screen) it gives me the error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

i have tried a lot of things. hope you can help. here is the code.

**App.js**--------------------------------------------------

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// PAGES

import LandingScreen from './src/landing';
import House from './src/house';

//CODE

function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
    return(
        <LandingScreen navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
    );
}

function HouseScreen({navigation}) {
    return(
        <House navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
    );
}



class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="House" component={HouseScreen}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )   
    }
    
}

const styles = {

}

export default App;
```

**landing.js**---------------------------------------------

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
//IMAGES

var myBackground = require('../assets/icons/lightblueBackground.png')
var buttonbannerlower = require('../assets/icons/buttonbannerlower.png')
var talkbuttonblue = require('../assets/icons/talkbuttonblue.png')
var gearIcon = require('../assets/icons/Gearicon.png')
var playIcon = require('../assets/icons/playicon.png')
var pointerIcon = require('../assets/icons/pointerIcon.png')
var houseIcon = require('../assets/icons/houseIcon.png')

//CODE



class Landing extends React.Component{

    render(){
            return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={{flex: 0.2, flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                            <ImageBackground source={buttonbannerlower} style={styles.imageBackground}>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={gearIcon} style={styles.iconsLeft}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={playIcon} style={styles.iconsLeft}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={talkbuttonblue} style={styles.blueButton}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity> 
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={pointerIcon} style={styles.iconPointer}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('House')}>
                                    <Image source={houseIcon} style={styles.iconsRight}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 0.2, alignItems: 'center',}}>
                            <Text>Hello</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            
            )       
    }
}



const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
        backgroundColor: '#ACE1EB'
    },
    imageBackground: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
    },
    blueButton: {
        height: 110,
        width: 110,
    },
    iconsLeft: {
        marginRight: 20,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 40,
        width: 40
    },
    iconsRight: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 40,
        width: 40
    },
    iconPointer: {
        marginLeft: 20,
        marginBottom: 10,
        height: 40,
        width: 40
    },
}
export default Landing;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add screen components like this:

```js
import LandingScreen from './src/landing';
import House from './src/house';

class App extends React.Component {
   
    render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={LandingScreen}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="House" component={House}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )   
    }
    
}
```

also to use props in a class component use this  keyword:
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('House')}>`

One more thing, to access props in a class component you call constructor like this :

```js
class Landing extends React.Component{
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
    render(){
            return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <View style={{flex: 0.2, flexDirection: 'row',}}>
                            <ImageBackground source={buttonbannerlower} style={styles.imageBackground}>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={gearIcon} style={styles.iconsLeft}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={playIcon} style={styles.iconsLeft}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={talkbuttonblue} style={styles.blueButton}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity> 
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Image source={pointerIcon} style={styles.iconPointer}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('House')}>
                                    <Image source={houseIcon} style={styles.iconsRight}/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </ImageBackground>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 0.2, alignItems: 'center',}}>
                            <Text>Hello</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
            
            )       
    }
}
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the reply. but sadly that does not take the error away.

Comment: can you try to add `constructor(props) { super(props);}` to your comps

Comment: sorry i am a total beginner. what are my comps? where should i add that line of code?

Comment: after i added in this.props.navigation.navigate('house') it gave me the following error "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: you should add it after `class Landing extends React.Component{` i will update my answer

Comment: it still gives the same error message. maybe this is a bridge too far for me.

Comment: Just follow the docs example:https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation, and be patient you will find where you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create functions for the screen components. Just do it like this:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

// PAGES

import LandingScreen from './src/landing';
import House from './src/house';

//CODE

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={LandingScreen}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="House" component={House}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )   
    }
    
}

const styles = {

}

export default App;
```

Then in your screen components, use the navigation function like this to navigate to other screens.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("House")}
```